# Javascript history.go

Tags: javascript

I need to give user one alert after saving an item.So I am using an open script to display this alert.But when I am moving out from that page and 
and coming back through history.go(-1) ,again getting the alert.How to make sure that this alert comes only if I am saving the item?

Comment: Posting some code will help a lot!

Comment: <% if(model.getItemForUpdate()!= null){%>
   var itemNumber = <%=model.getItemNumber()%>
   <%if("Y".equals(model.getItemForUpdate())){%>
    alert('Item('+itemNumber+') has been successfully Saved.');
   <%}else{%>
    alert('Item('+itemNumber+') has been successfully Saved.');
   <%}%>
   <%}%>

Comment: You are doing an "if x then y else y". You can shorten that to: `<% if (model.getItemForUpdate()!= null) { %> alert('Item(<%=model.getItemNumber()%>) has been successfully Saved.'); <% } %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `history,go(-1)` then you are going to the page that saved the record, so it will be saving the record again.

It might work with `history.go(-2)` if you came from the page that shows the result, but it might not update with the saved record because the page is cached. Go on to the page that shows the result, instead of trying to find it in the history.